# How lockfree containers react to concurrent partitioning and sorting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency, tbb

How two standart algorithms like partition and sorting performed form 2 different threads at the same time are handeled via concurrent containers (for example in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) or [tbb](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm) implementations)?

Answer (score 1):

Boost has lockfree queues and a stack. One doesn't sort or partition these.

On superficial inspection of the documentation, TBB has concurrent_hash_map, and queue classes for which the same goes.

Only `concurrent_vector` from TBB would raise this question. The docs describe it as follows:

> A `concurrent_vector<T>` is a dynamically growable array of `T`

However, just the storage (re)allocation is lockfree threadsafe, not the elements itself;

> A concurrent_vector never moves an element until the array is cleared, which can be an advantage over the STL std::vector even for single-threaded code

And

> Operations on concurrent_vector are concurrency safe with respect to growing, not for clearing or destroying a vector. Never invoke method clear() if there are other operations in flight on the concurrent_vector.

Hence if you want to sort a concurrent_vector you might

- want to mutually exclude access; if latency is crucial you might use an atomic spinlock instead of fullblown mutex, but anyways you need a synchronization
- want to consider copying to a sorted range leaving the source entries unmodified; this could be done without further locking (assuming the read operations on the vector elements are thread safe), see e.g. **[`std::partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy)**